# How can i keep an entry in my routing table, even when the associated interface goes down?

Tags: linux, router, routing, dhcp, slackware

I have a linux box set up as my internet router. I have the `eth0` interface connected to the lan, and the `eth1` interface connected to a pppoa modem and configured with dhcp to my public ip. Due to issues with ARP i have to connect to the internet using the modem itself (which has the ip 172.16.0.1) as the next hop. To do this, i use the following 2 lines:

```
route add -host 172.16.0.1 dev eth1
route add default gw 172.16.0.1
```

This usually runs after the interface has been configured with dhcp, and all is well. The problem comes in when the modem gets disconnected, reconnected and allocated a new ip address by my isp. When the dhcpc daemon reconfigured the `eth1` interface for the new ip, my routing table loses the entries it needs to get to the internet, meaning i need to enter the 2 `route` commands over again. Is there a way to force linux to keep the routes, or possibly to have them added automatically when `dhcpcd` does it's thing?

A google search for "persistent routes" brings up ways to keep routes across boots, but that's not what i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can usually setup default gateway in your DHCP server so whenever it assigns IPs it will also provide a default gateway for clients to use. Consult your DHCP server's configuration on how to do this.

**Option 2**

Other way this can be accomplished on the client is by creating an dhcpcd hook in in `/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks` (directory might be different on slackware but I highly doubt it). Create a new file called `40-route` with contents:

```
route add -host 172.16.0.1 dev eth1
route add default gw 172.16.0.1
```

Or alternatively this should also work:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 via 172.16.0.1
```

This should execute this command after dhcpcd gets new IP. You have to change `192.168.0.0/24` to what your network is using.

Comment: +1 for DHCP hooks. I had to discover it one day when I had same question. It works well.

Comment: It's important to note that the interface through which i talk to `172.16.0.1` /doesn't/ have an ip in the `172.16/24` block. That's why the first `route` line is needed. Therefore i can't merely have `dhcpcd` set up the default gateway. Also, there is no `/usr/lib/dhcpcd` directory on my machine.

Comment: `find / | grep dhcpcd-hooks` turned up `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks`

Comment: After briefly skimming `DHCPCD-RUN-HOOKS(8)` I found `$interface` and `$reason`. One short `if` statement later and I have what I need, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here's what worked for me.

```
# /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-route
if [ "$reason" = "BOUND" ] && [ "$interface" = "eth1" ]; then
  route add -host 172.16.0.1 dev eth1
  route add default gw 172.16.0.1
fi
```